# Blazor server javascript not inserting elements as an MVC app would

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm facing a little challenge here.

I'm trying to implement ads in my blazor server solution, and i cannot get it to work. So i've come up with a small MVC app where it works.

I must say that the blazor app is for a client i'm working for, and I don't know who supplies these adds. They send the code that i must implement for it to work.

Here is the stuff that they have asked me to implement in the head of the webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var utag_data = {
    }
    </script>
    <!-- Loading script asynchronously -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(a,b,c,d){
    a='//partnerurl';
    b=document;c='script';d=b.createElement(c);d.src=a;d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;
    a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a);
    })();
    </script>

    <script async='async' src='https://macro.adnami.io/macro/spec/adsm.macro.someId.js'></script>
    <script>
        var adsmtag = adsmtag || {};
        adsmtag.cmd = adsmtag.cmd || [];
    </script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.cookielaw.org">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/tcf.stub.js" as="script"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/tcf.stub.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net">
    <script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
    <script>
      var googletag = window.googletag || {};
      googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
      window.yb_configuration = {"domain":"clientdomain"};
      (function (y, i, e, l, d, b, I, R, D) {
        d.Yieldbird = d.Yieldbird || {};
        d.Yieldbird.cmd = d.Yieldbird.cmd || [];
        l.cmd.push(function () {l.pubads().disableInitialLoad();});
        b = i.createElement('script'); b.async = true;
        b.src = (e === 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//jscdn.yieldbird.com/' + y + '/yb.js';
        I = i.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        (I.parentNode || i.head).insertBefore(b, I);
      })('950dff97-bb8d-4667-952b-d72ce8bbe88b', document, document.location.protocol, googletag, window);
    </script>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        googletag.pubads().enableLazyLoad({
          fetchMarginPercent: 150,
          renderMarginPercent: 75,
          mobileScaling: 1.5
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And for each add placement i've received some html/javascript i must place at the location.

Heres an example:

```
<!-- /x,y/domain/domain.dk/billboard_1 -->

<script async="async" src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js">
    </script>

<script>
var googletag = googletag || {};googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(
        function() {
            var YBmapping = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([931,0],[[930,180]]).addSize([0,0],[]).build(); 
            googletag.defineSlot('/x,y/domain/domain.dk/billboard_1', [[930, 180]], 'div-gpt-ad-billboard_1').defineSizeMapping(YBmapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
</script>


<div id='div-gpt-ad-billboard_1'>
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
        googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-billboard_1');});
    </script>
</div>
```

I've obfuscted some variables. But i guess you get the hang of it..

This is from the MVC app, and it works. It places extra html inside my div with the div-gpt-ad-billboard_1 id. So on the website the HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="div-gpt-ad-billboard_1">
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
        googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-billboard_1');});
    </script>
<div id="google_ads_iframe_/x,y/domain/domain.dk/billboard_1_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; width: 930px; height: 0px;"></div></div>
```

And if i deploy my MVC app to the live endpoint we have, an iFrame is inserted into the div with the google_ads_iframe Id, where the add is displayed.

Now on my blazor app, this doesn't happen.

I've created a blazor component which contains the ad i want to place. It looks like this:

```
<script async="async" suppress-error="BL9992" src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js">
    </script>

<script suppress-error="BL9992">
var googletag = googletag || {};googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>
<script suppress-error="BL9992">
googletag.cmd.push(
        function() {
            var YBmapping = googletag.sizeMapping().addSize([931,0],[[930,180]]).addSize([0,0],[]).build(); 
            googletag.defineSlot('x,y/domain/domain.dk/billboard_1', [[930, 180]], 'div-gpt-ad-billboard_1').defineSizeMapping(YBmapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
            googletag.enableServices();
            console.log(googletag);
        });
</script>


<div id='div-gpt-ad-billboard_1'>
    <script suppress-error="BL9992">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
            googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-billboard_1');});
    </script>
</div>
```

As i understand it you cannot directly call script tags in blazor components, but they work if you add the suppress-error, and i can atleast get it to console log from them.

The head is the same in the blazor app as in the MVC app, as script tag works fine in _Host.cshtml in blazor.

The issue is that for my blazor app the ad component looks like this on the live endpoint:

```
<div id="div-gpt-ad-billboard_1"><script><!--!-->
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-billboard_1');});
    </script></div>
```

Notice that the entire div with the google iframe ID is missing. It's as if it doesn't update anything. I've tried to call statehaschanged from OnInitializedAsync. Nothing happens, and i guess it makes sense, since nothing is probably added to the render tree that statehaschanged activates the rerendering of.

Does anyone have any idea, how i can get it to work like the MVC app ?

Comment: When you render content from Blazor and then something else is going to alter it (in this case the scripts will) you should make your component override ShouldRender and return false, so it only renders once - as subsequent renders could invalidate anything the scripts have done. So try that first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't seem to help though :/

Comment: In that case I would suggest you do it more the Blazor way and put the JS calls into a script that you load as a module in your component and then call via JSInterop. The first script looks like it should be loaded in the header though. Then your component would just be an empty div with the id "div-gpt-ad-billboard_1" and some interop code in OnAfterRenderAsync when firstRender is true.

Comment: Yeah. I'm considering that also. I think that the issue is that those functions that googletag.cmd.push does is called by a third party script, that is loaded. And i'm not sure if i will be able to react to that event, and rerender. But i'll give it a try. I have managed to get something to work, by calling an API that return a cshtml view, and put that into an iFrame. The issue with that is that it no longer responds to the cookie consent :)